# Translation of 閉まらくなった

Tags: translation

I have the following to translate.

```
車は、
古くて、
パワーウインドーの窓が時々閉まらくなったり、
ヘッドライトが消えなくなったりして
困るので、
主人に早めに直してもらわなくてはなりません。
```

So far I have the following.

```
The car
is old and
it does things like the power windows sometimes become ...
and the headlights become not turning off and
it is a problem so
I have to have my husband fix it relatively early.
```

I am confused by the `閉まらくなった`. I would understand if it were `閉まらなくなった` (become not closing). I am not sure if this was just a typo by my professor or whether it is some other structure.

Comment: This is almost certainly a typo of 閉まらなくなったり.

Comment: I confirmed with my teacher. This was indeed a typo on his part. Thanks all. :)

Comment: Okay, I'm closing this question because it's about a typo that has no linguistic significance.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a typo. My question was if it meant something. I would delete it, but you can't delete when there are answers.

Answer (score 1):

"stopped closing properly"

Please disregard if we are done with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Typo aside, I still found the sentence to be rather long and unwieldy.

I wonder if this is just my bias as a native English speaker or was the original sentence eloquent and efficient in Japanese?

I know that many on this site dislike posing questions in an answer so perhaps I will remove this later to placate the ire of other users here, but I am interested in understanding the seeming discrepancy between my understanding of this sentence and how it might be working.

But maybe there was a period after ヘッドライトが消えなくなったりして and the OP did not post it?

Anyways, here is my loose translation attempt.

I believe i smudged the meaning a little in my attempt to make it sound like natural English.

> My car is so old that I have this problem where sometimes the power windows don't close properly and the headlights don't turn off so I have to ask my husband to fix it for me soon.

There is so much information in one sentence that I found it to be more natural when divided in two:

> My car is so old that I have this problem where sometimes the power windows don't close properly and the headlights don't turn off. So I have to ask my husband to fix it for me soon.